# Nativescript Navigation Logic

Tags: javascript, nativescript

Just have a quick question regarding navigation logic in a Javascript Nativescript application.

Many of the applications seem to tie navigation to the views js file.
The application that I’m making shares a lot of this navigation between the JS files and I’m looking for a way to reduce the amount of repeatable code I’m using.

I know Angular has the router to handle this but I’m wondering if there’s something I can do with Javascript Nativescript to include all of the navigation logic inside one file.

At the moment I’m navigating like this:-

xml:

```
<Label text=“Navigation Label" tap="navigate" />
```

js:

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
function navigationOptions(moduleVar) {
 frameModule.topmost().navigate({
   moduleName: moduleVar,
   transition: { name: "fade" },
   backstackVisible: false,
   clearHistory: true
 });
}

exports.navigate = function(args) {
 navigationOptions("views/catalog/catalog");
}
```

The JS has to be repeated into each folder at the moment and I’m just looking for a way to tidy up my code, do you have recommendations or resources that I can find to help with this?

Comment: you could follow the `sample-Groceries` as example - https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/javascript/app/shared/navigation.js, where has been shown, how you could include the whole navigation in one file.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to set up a cleaner navigation due to the provided resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to the resource provided by Nikolay and created by TJ:
https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/blob/javascript/app/shared/navigation.js

First a navigation.js file is created within the shared folder:

**app/shared/navigation.js**

```
var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var drawer;
module.exports = {
  /* Settings navigation */
  goToSettingsPage: function() {
    frameModule.topmost().navigate({
      moduleName: "views/settings/settings",
      transition: { name: "fade" },    // <-- This line
      backstackVisible: false,
    });
  },
```

You'll then need to call the js file in your view js file:

**app/views/dashboard.js**

```
var navigation = require("../../shared/navigation");
```

and you will also need to call the functions set up in navigation.js

```
exports.goToSettingsPage = navigation.goToSettingsPage;
```

Then you can simply call the function on the desired component.

```
tap="goToSettingsPage"
```

I'm still not 100% fussed on the fact that you have to call each navigation function but it's certainly better than what I had previously.